# How to check two input is already exist in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have roles tables. When storing new data in roles table I need to check role_name and role_id is already exist. How can check in laravel?

`id role_name role_id
  1    admin     1
  2    user      2`

**RoleRequest.php**

```
class RoleRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'role_name' => 'required|unique:role|max:50',
            'role_id'  => 'required|unique:role|max:10'
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the field **exists** in the database, you can use the [exists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-exists) validation rule to do this.

It can be used as follows:

```
exists:table,column
```

So, for e.g,

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'role_name' => 'exists:roles,role_name''
    ];
}
```

However, if you want to ensure that the field is **unique** in your database, you can use the [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique) validation rule, like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'role_name' => 'unique:roles,role_name''
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unique validation rule, but you also need to set the column name

```
return [
      'role_name' => 'required|unique:roles,role_name|max:50',
      'role_id'  => 'required|unique:roles,role_id|max:10'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'role_name' => 'required|max:50|unique:roles,role_name',
        'role_id'  => 'required|max:10|unique:roles,role_id'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function rules()
{
return [
    'role_name' => 'required|max:50|unique:roles,role_name',
    'role_id'  => 'required|max:10|unique:roles,role_id'
];
}
```